# Next.js deploy with build folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment, web-deployment

I am new to next and wanted to ask if i can deploy my app on netlify with build folder ?? if yes how?

i tried to upload the .next folder but netlify says "please upload folder with index.html in it".

Comment: do you have index.html files check it again.. then follow this link https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/11/30/how-to-deploy-next.js-sites-to-netlify/

Comment: the error says that your folder should contain an `index.html` file which is the root file of your application